# HTTP GET request responses very slow when add Header "Range"

Tags: android, http, network-programming

When add header `Range` to request, the speed is about 3KB/s.
Without `Range`, the speed is about 200KB/s.
Anybody know why?

```
GET /assets/svn-book.pdf HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=0-1945365
Host: sethfeng.github.io
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.3.2 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.3) GCDHTTPRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

The range is somehow wrong. Reading from [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) under Range, w3 suggest that all should be OK, but either your server is getting it wrong, or the item you are trying to get is much bigger than 1048575 bytes, which explains the lower speed easily. Use different values for Range and check result.

Comment: I tried. The values of Range(start/end) has nothing to do with the speed.

Comment: [link](http://www.rhyshaden.com/http.htm). Maybe you are missing some more of headers, or your server doesn't support the range header. In my opinion, range header affects the speed and you have the proof for that. You can check also [this](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html) to understand the range header.